# Unable to connect wifi in Raspberry Pi 3 and os design for navio

Tags: pi-2, linux

The link below shows the images of the output error, i`ve been working this for hours I follow instructions from [here](https://docs.emlid.com/navio2/common/ardupilot/configuring-raspberry-pi/) but still doesnt work . Hoping that someone would help me figure out the problem , Im using raspberry pi 3 model b++ , and raspbian jessie os from the [here](https://docs.emlid.com/navio2/common/ardupilot/configuring-raspberry-pi/)

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/haJxF.jpg)

Update heres the file from /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNTJq.jpg)!

```
country=PH
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="EML33T2"
    #psk="emrooftop"
    psk=c150059ac2d9df589127a8ee0a1cc475099c2d6e60ea48644c21684cb7ee6b23
}

network={
    ssid= "test"
    psk= "testingi"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

For interfaces

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)

# Please note that this file is written to be used with dhcpcd
# For static IP, consult /etc/dhcpcd.conf and 'man dhcpcd.conf'

# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
sources-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet manual

allow-hotplug intwifi0
iface intwifi0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see the file `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and the `/etc/network/interfaces` because the error obtains of parsing the needed files. And finally he could not start the wlan0 interface

Comment: @bierschi I updated my post , link is the file in mentioned directory

Answer (score 0):

I think `/etc/network/interfaces` is configured correctly. So change your `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file into this way:

```
country=PH
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="your_SSID_from_router"
    psk="your_secret_password"
}
```

Ensure that `ssid` and `psk` absolutely correct to the settings of your router. 
Set the psk into quotes. And write only one `network={}` statement into this file and try to restart your wlan interface

Useful commands:

scan available networks:

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

switch on and off the wlan0 interface

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

restart the whole network interface:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: After using the command iwlist wlan0 scan @bierschi I got this error [image](https://imgur.com/a/hdn8C)

Comment: no wlan device is running. First ensure with `ifconfig` that a wlan interface is up like `wlan0` or `wlan1`. If one wlan interface is up you can use the command `sudo iwlist wlan0/wlan1 scan`.